# Statistical significance between two groups of different size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I'm trying to test statistical significance on a sample of two groups that I have, but I'm getting tripped up over the details:

I have a sample of 30 days of Group A and Group B. Events in group A and B are tallied numerically and are 0 when nothing happens. I also have the data of how many trials were done each day. The problem that I struggle with is that after 30 days, Group A has 1500 trials while Group B has 1000 trials.

Obviously my null hypothesis is that both of these distributions are the same and I want to test against that.

Should I just do a t-test based on the 30 days as a sample, given that the samples are inequal, or should I weigh the sample in a specific manner (IE reduce the values of B or have the entirety of the data be in %)?

Comment: The t-test works out the different sample sizes. You can proceed with that test without being concerned about the different sample sizes. // In a designed experiment, the most powerful two-sample test that has $N$ subjects allocates $N/2$ to each group, but you have a perfectly valid test with uneven sample sizes, if that’s just the way the observations go.

Comment: So do I test observed successes over 30 days of A versus 30 days of B, or do I draw up the entire list of trials for A and B? I'm trying to avoid doing the latter. My idea was to draw up successes divided by trials for every day and then run a t-test based on that.

Comment: just wanted to add something: @Dave, Please correct me, if I'm wrong, but i think, the encountering of unequal sample sizes in t-test has a specific name, and is called Satterthwaite Approximation ? Page 2: https://www.unm.edu/~marcusj/2Sampletex2.pdf,

Comment: @PatrickBormann That is incorrect. That has to do with testing when there is unequal variance in the populations (Welch test...uses Satterthwaite to calculate degrees of freedom). I recommend t-testing this way unless there is strong evidence to suggest equal variance. In particular, I would not use a hypothesis test (or even graphical analysis) to screen for equal variance. Conveniently, this is the default setting in R.

Comment: Ok got it, but should Sefam not took a a random subsample of the 1500 that equals 1000 because the t-test only has a maximum power of the minimum sample size of two groups? And What is about the welch-test?

Comment: I ended up just dividing successes by the amount of trials in a given day for 30 days, and did a t-test between the two groups based on that.